# How to get path from a Content file from Helpers in C#/.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

This is the structure of my solution in the VS 2012 Solution Explorer:

```
abcWeb
 - Properties
 - References
 - Service References
 - App_Data
 - Areas
 - -abcArea
 - - - Controlers
 - - - - abcController
 - - - ViewModels
 - - - - abcViewModel
 - - - Views
 - - - - abcView
 - Content
 - - css
 - - images
 - - fonts
 - - scripts
 - - templates
 - - - abc.html   
 - Globals
 - Helpers
 - - abcHelper.cs 
. . .
```

My question is:

I have a method to send an email in the `abcHelper` and this method reads the abc.html file from the Content/templates, to include as the body of the email. What is the path as a string to pass as a parameter in the `System.IO.File.ReadAllText(...)` function?

Here is the method:

```
    public void SendWelcomeTemplate()
    {
        string templatePath = @"../Content/templates/abc.html"; // This doesn't work!

        var emailBody = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(templatePath);

        SendEmail(strToEmailAddress, strEmailSubject, emailBody);
    }
```

I appreciate very much any help.

Comment: have you tried `~`? `@"~/Content/templates/abc.html"`

Comment: @christiandev Yes, that gives me error too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
string templatePath = Server.MapPath("/Content/templates/abc.html");
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked for me. I used: var templatePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Content/templates/abc.html");